# eleastic search 10 hits only

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch for the first time but when I do a search I am getting a JSON response from elastic search which gives me the first 10 results. How do I then request the next 10 results and so on?

Ive looked on the API but this dosn't give much insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `size` and `from` parameter - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html